# FaceTime does not appear in "Apps Using WLAN & Cellular"

Tags: ios, network, wifi, facetime, cellular-data

I downloaded FaceTime (latest but I don't know the version) on App Store. When I start it and click contact, it pops up "No Network Connection", "Allow FaceTime to access WLAN networks.", followed "Cancel" and "WLAN Settings" button.

When I click "WLAN Settings", then click "Apps Using WLAN & Cellular", I can't find the "FaceTime" App.

Is it a bug in FaceTime or my current iOS 14.8?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my iPhone 8 Plus (System version 15.6).
Whenever I tried to click on a name to make a FaceTime call, this error pops up:
`No Network Connection, Allow FaceTime to access WLAN networks.`
When I clicked on the `WLAN Settings`, FaceTime did not appear **on that list**.

(I had uninstalled `FaceTime` before.)

##### Soved By One Click:

Click on the green button called `New FaceTime`, then there is a popup pane ask for network permission.
I allowed it to use both WLAN and CELLULAR.
Then the `FaceTime` appeared in the **previous mentioned list**.

Hope this helps!